# How do I limit the number of total appended elements to a div?

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons that add two different images to  a div respectively. I have been able to limit their individual appends four. So I can add four of each image (eight total). However, I want to limit the total amount of images to six. For example, if I added four of "image1", I could only add 2 of "image2".

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var maxAppend = 0;
    $("#addbiscuit").click(function () {
   
        var $imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='biscuit'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/102_biscuit.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='closebtn' width='22px'></div></div>");
         if (maxAppend >= 4) return;
        $("#samplebox").append($imageElement);
        maxAppend++;
        $("i").append(addinput);
        
         
    });

    $("#samplebox").on('click', '.closebtn', function(){
        $(this).closest('.biscuit').remove();
        maxAppend--;
    })
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var maxAppend = 0;
    $("#addcement").click(function () {
   
        var $imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='cement'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/61_cement_smallglass.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='closebtn' width='22px'></div></div>");
         if (maxAppend >= 4) return;
        $("#samplebox").append($imageElement);
        maxAppend++;
        $("i").append(addinput);
        
         
    });

    $("#samplebox").on('click', '.closebtn', function(){
        $(this).closest('.cement').remove();
        maxAppend--;
    })
});
</script>
<div class="firstdiv"><button id ="addbiscuit" >add biscuit</button></div>
<div class="seconddiv"><button id ="addcement" >add cement</button></div>

<div id="samplebox">
<p> SAMPLE BOX </p>

</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Why not just counting the total amount of [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var maxAppend = 6;
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#addbiscuit").click(function (){
       var imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='biscuit'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/102_biscuit.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='close_bisq_btn' width='22px'></div></div>");
     if (maxAppend > 0) {
          $("#samplebox").append(imageElement);
          maxAppend--; 
     }
  });

  $("#samplebox").on('click', '.close_bisq_btn', function(){
      $(this).closest('.biscuit').remove();
      maxAppend++;
  });

  $("#addcement").click(function () {
       var imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='cement'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/61_cement_smallglass.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='close_cem_btn' width='22px'></div></div>");
       if (maxAppend > 0) {
           $("#samplebox").append(imageElement);
           maxAppend--;
       }
  });

  $("#samplebox").on('click', '.close_cem_btn', function(){
       $(this).closest('.cement').remove();
       maxAppend++;
  })
  });
</script>
<div class="firstdiv">
    <button id ="addbiscuit" >add biscuit</button>
</div>
<div class="seconddiv">
    <button id ="addcement" >add cement</button>
</div>
<div id="samplebox">
  <p> SAMPLE BOX </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. I lost my ability to only add "4" of each individually, but this will do. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are close. First - don't use 2 document ready functions and make the variable available for both click methods (which will be the case if you are inside the same ready function body) - this should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxAppend = 6: // your total value
    var currAppended = 0; // currently added

    $("#addcement").click(function () {   
        var $imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='cement'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/61_cement_smallglass.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='closebtn' width='22px'></div></div>");
        if (currAppended >= maxAppend) return; // if added >= max return
        $("#samplebox").append($imageElement);
        currAppended++; // increase the variable
        $("i").append(addinput);
    });

    $("#addbiscuit").click(function () {
        var $imageElement = $("<div class='sample_holder' ><div class='biscuit'><input type='image' src='Images/sample_thumbs/102_biscuit.jpg' width='5%' name='closeStory' class='closebtn' width='22px'></div></div>");
        if (currAppended >= maxAppend) return; // same here
        $("#samplebox").append($imageElement);
        currAppended++; // increase the variable
        $("i").append(addinput);    
    });

    $("#samplebox").on('click', '.close_bisq_btn', function(){
        $(this).closest('.biscuit').remove();
        currAppended++; // decrease the variable
    });

    $("#samplebox").on('click', '.closebtn', function(){
        $(this).closest('.cement').remove();
        currAppended--; // decrease the variable
    })
});
```